# Insert SVG in email signature

Tags: microsoft-outlook, images, svg, email-signature

Is there a way, in Outlook, to insert the SVG vector picture(logo) instead of JPEG/PNG one, and use it in a signature?

I tried but it want me to convert the SVG into another format, I would like to keep vectorial image to be able to visualise in different resolutions and even with deactivated pictures.

Comment: Email signatures are pointless and should be discouraged. The legalese is worthless nonsense and they rarely contain anything of value.

Comment: SVGs are just XML files, however I'm uncertain if it would display as an image if only the XML content was pasted into the signature box _(to see the XML content, open the `.svg` within a text editor)_

Answer (score 0):

I have found a similar thread and here's solution you could refer to: [Use SVG in signature](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/office-365/use-svg-in-signature/m-p/1207205)

Additionally, [How can I embed SVG into HTML in an email, so that it's visible in most/all email browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37753911/how-can-i-embed-svg-into-html-in-an-email-so-that-its-visible-in-most-all-emai) you could also refer to, hope it help.